Numpy std giving completely wrong result
I have the following script that generate 3 blobs, and plots the radius an standard deviation of all.
for the third blob (centered in (20,1)) i get a std that is bigger than the radius (that is mathematically impossible, given that it is the biased uncorrected estimator)

in the figure, you can see the problem in the third cluster, as the dashed line represent the standard deviation.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?
I paste the script:
from calendar import c
from operator import le
from statistics import variance
from matplotlib import axis
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rich import print
import matplotlib as mpl

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import src

src.vis.set_matplotlib_params()

# generate three blobs
centers=[(1,1), (11,13), (20,1)]
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=600, n_features=2, random_state=3, cluster_std=[1,3,1], centers=centers)

# plot the blobls

colorlist = ["#ebac23", "#b80058", "#008cf9", "#006e00", "#00bbad", "#d163e6", "#b24502", "#ff9287", "#5954d6", "#00c6f8", "#878500", "#00a76c", "#bdbdbd"]
cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colorlist[0:len(np.unique(y))])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap, marker='.', s=10)

# plot the centers
for center in centers:
    ax.scatter(center[0], center[1], c='black', marker='x', s=100)
# compute the radiuses
radiuses = dict()
stds = dict()
for center,y_int in zip(centers, np.arange(len(centers))): # for each cluster
    current_pts = X[y==y_int, :]
    N = current_pts.shape[0]
    print(f"Y_int={y_int}, \t current data = {current_pts}")
    dists = np.linalg.norm(current_pts-center, axis=1)
    radiuses[y_int] = np.max(dists)
    stds[y_int] = np.std(current_pts)
print(radiuses)
print(stds)

# plot the radiuses
for center,y_int in zip(centers, np.unique(y)):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(center, radiuses[y_int], fill=False, color=cmap(y_int), linestyle='-', linewidth=.5))
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(center, stds[y_int], fill=False, color=cmap(y_int), linestyle='--', linewidth=.5))


ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

I tried to move the third cluster, and i noticed that the problem is more evident when the center is far from the bisect line (y=x) in the plane

After a quick look hands off I notice that you apply max to dists, while std to current_points. While dists is a sequence of numbers, current_points is a sequence of pairs. I am not sure, how std is defined on multidimensional arrays.

Indeed: you're taking the standard deviation of a 200 by 2 array, which just amounts to taking the standard deviation of 400 values: half of which are x values, half are y values. The result is, for the points around (20, 1), a large standard deviation, since all values together vary between roughly 1 and 20. For the other points, you don't notice this, because x and y are very similar. So: what do you want to get for the standard deviation of 2D points? Perhaps simply np.std(dists)?

Why do you call np.std(current_pts) and not : np.std(current_pts, axis=1) (std-dev applied separately in each dimension -- not really compatible with the L2 norm) or np.std(dist) (std-dev of the L2 norm) or even np.std(current_pts-center) (certainly the wame for the L1 norm) ? In the current code, x and y values are mixed together in the std-dev computation. Since values are not centered in x but are in y, the std-dev is artificially higher than what you expect. This does not make any sense to me to compute that.

@JérômeRichard thank you! I indeed wanted to compute np.std(current_pts-center).
I somewhat assumed that the std method computed the mean (center of mass) if presented with multidimensional data, and not compute the std along just one dimension.
I think this solves my problem
